# External Hard Disk not showing in fdisk -l output

Tags: hard-drive, fdisk

I just bought a new hard disk and fdisk -l doesn't show me this hard disk.
Below is what **dmesg** says about it-->

```
giroo@ubuntu:~$ dmesg

[   86.912522] usb 3-6: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd

[   87.117713] usb 3-6: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=231a

[   87.117718] usb 3-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3

[   87.117721] usb 3-6: Product: Expansion

[   87.117724] usb 3-6: Manufacturer: Seagate

[   87.117726] usb 3-6: SerialNumber: 2HC015KJ

[   87.188938] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage

[   87.212010] scsi host2: uas

[   87.212123] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas

[   87.212552] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        0708 PQ
```

And some other time the output of 'dmesg' was:

```
[ 3360.775246] usb 3-6: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd

[ 3360.980190] usb 3-6: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=231a

[ 3360.980193] usb 3-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3

[ 3360.980195] usb 3-6: Product: Expansion

[ 3360.980196] usb 3-6: Manufacturer: Seagate

[ 3360.980197] usb 3-6: SerialNumber: 2HC015KJ

[ 3360.981283] scsi host2: uas

[ 3360.981916] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        0708 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6

[ 3361.019597] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0

[ 3409.158055] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...

[ 3430.249974] .

[ 3472.817556] .

[ 3472.817781] ready

[ 3472.818450] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 281474976710654 512-byte logical blocks: (144 PB/128 PiB)

[ 3472.818454] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks

[ 3472.818615] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off

[ 3472.818619] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 53 00 00 08

[ 3472.818919] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA

[ 3472.901789] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE

[ 3472.901806] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] 

[ 3472.901811] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: No additional sense information

[ 3472.901821] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 02 00 00

[ 3472.901836] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 6

[ 3472.901844] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 3, async page read
[ 3473.066103] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.

[ 3473.386177] Dev sdb: unable to read RDB block 0

[ 3473.786210]  sdb: unable to read partition table

[ 3473.787545] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

**and the fdisk -l output looks like --->**

```
sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for xxx: 

Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors

Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes

Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disklabel type: dos

Disk identifier: 0x5287eef0

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type

/dev/sda1  *         2048 964362239 964360192 459.9G 83 Linux

/dev/sda2       964364286 976771071  12406786   5.9G  5 Extended

/dev/sda5       964364288 976771071  12406784   5.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

One additional behavior is that when i plug-in this hard disk and try to open **BIOS** setup, it doesn't open and sometimes if it does, it gets hanging- no up-down button work.
I am using ubuntu 17.04 here.

[Disk utility Displays this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzfeP.png)

output of `ls /dev/ | grep sd` is
    sda

```
sda1

sda2

sda5

sdb
```

when i try to formate it from the Disk Utility----> 
it throws an error that device is too large to hold NTFS volume and the limit is 256TB.

Comment: Disk utillity says 144115 TB for your USB disk /dev/sdb ... somthing must be wrong with it. Also it don't seem to have ant partitions.

Comment: yeah, right! i don't understand that either.
Is there a thing like a hard disk can not be supported for Linux distros, sometimes?

Comment: Zesty (17.04) reached EOL on January 13, 2018. It would be advisable to upgrade to a supported version.

Comment: Note that :
even BIOS setup is not working while this hard disk is plugged-in.
so maybe it's not because of the operating system maybe?